# complining error in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code in python. But when i submit the code on the spoj, it returns me the runtime error (NZEC). Can anybody help me to solve this problem? I will be very thankful.

```
    import numpy as np
    import sys

    x = sys.argv[0]
    input = open('1.in')
    lines = input.readline()
    z = []

    for line in input:
         lst = line.strip().split(' ')
         z.append(int(lst[0]))

    size = len(z)
    M = np.zeros((len(z),len(z)))

    for i in range(size-1, -1, -1):
         for j in range(size-1, i-1, -1):
             if i == size-1:
               M[i,j] = z[i]
             else:
                if j > i:
                      M[i,j] = M[i+1,j] + [j-i]
                elif j == i:
                     M[i,j] = z[i] + M[j+1, (j+1):].min()
    cost = int(M[j, j:].min())
    print cost
```

Comment: Any chance you could review the indentation? It's kind of important in Python. Also, a description of what you're trying to achieve and the full error message would be useful.

Comment: What is the *code* trying to achieve? And does SPOJ just say "runtime error" or does it give more information? And please edit your post with the correct indentation.

Comment: Here is the link of the question, i am trying to solve.  http://www.spoj.com/problems/SERVS/ . SPOJ is returning me "runtime error (NZEC)"

Comment: I also have indentation my code

Comment: Thank you, I have extended my answer with a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

[NZEC](http://www.spoj.com/tutorials/USERS/#submit) stands for "non-zero exit code":

> NZEC (non-zero exit code) - this message means that the program exited returning a value different from 0 to the shell. For languages such as C, this probably means you forgot to add "return 0" at the end of the program. For interpreted languages (including JAVA *[and Python]*) NZEC will usually mean that your program either crashed or raised an uncaught exception.

This doesn't give you much useful information; you need to run your code locally and make sure that it works correctly before uploading. For example, whether due to a copy-paste problem or otherwise, the code you have posted is not valid Python; it is incorrectly indented, which would certainly cause an "uncaught exception".

If I comment out the input/file handling part (i.e. everything before `size = len(z)`) and directly set `z = [4, 3, 2, 1]` I get `cost == 6`, as per the example answer. Therefore the problem is in your input code.

I believe SPOJ requires you to use `raw_input`, rather than `sys.argv` or reading from a file:

```
servers = int(raw_input())
z = []
for _ in range(servers):
    z.append(int(raw_input())
```

Comment: I made the changes according to you but it returns the compilation error. the test files of the program consists of the integer values in line without spaces, for example one of the test file is  1216121919137718371914

Comment: I don't see how you can proceed here. Without spaces, how do you know how many digits `n` is? According to the description on SPOJ "First line of the input consists of the number `n` of servers `(1 ≤ n ≤ 1000)`. In the next `n` lines you are given the placement costs, in line `i + 1` you are given the placement cost `ci` of server `Si`."

Comment: yes, in spoj the input is given in the same way as in the example of the problem. That is way i have included the part "for line in input:" in the programme

Answer (score 0):

NZEC means that the code is throwing an exception.

I am not familiar with SPOJ, but apparently you are supposed to read your input from `stdin`. If that is the case, I would guess that the exception is being thrown at `open('1.in')`.

Try to change

```
input = open('1.in')
```

to

```
input = sys.stdin
```

and check what happens.

Comment: No. it does not work. Again it is showing the same error "runtime erroe (NZEC).